# fstab in Ubuntu Core 16 to mount external HD

Tags: ubuntu-core

How do you mount a drive in Ubuntu Core? Can you use the fstab? Or is there another way? I don't want to get started an realise you cannot mount an external drive.

When you're in the fstab, it says not to manually write it and to go to `/etc/writable` but how do you add the fstab? HERE BE DRAGONS I fear

Comment: ...fstab should work, as well as the `mount` command.

Comment: I am not sure what answer do you expect. Does mikewhatever's reply satisfies you?

Comment: I need to know how to edit the fstab as you're warned not to do it

Comment: /etc/writeable does not exist on my 16.04, and fstab contains no such warning.  What OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16. Not standard Ubuntu

Comment: same problem here.

On Ubuntu Core when I opened /etc/fstab i get the following:
"
# Auto-generated by /init
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND - YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN "   however I could not find where in the /init I should add my mount

Answer (score 3):

use the systemd to mount a drive on Ubuntu Core 16.04:

**Step 1:** Identlify your uuid by using

> sudo blkid

**Step 2:** Using "vi" or another editor create a mount unit file for systemd to use. If you want the mount point to be "/media/data" then create the file "/etc/systemd/system/media-data.mount"

> sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/media-data.mount

**Step 3:** Add information about your drive to the mount unit file (media-data.mount)

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for data

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007
Where=/media/data
Type=ntfs
Options=umask=0000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step 4:** reload systemd

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload

**Step 5:** Start the unit

> sudo systemctl start media-data.mount

**Step 6:** To enable auto mount do:

> sudo systemctl enable media-data.mount

**Step 7: Have fun.**

**Information sources:**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/systemd.mount.5.html

https://flexion.org/posts/2016-12-raspberry-pi-3-powered-nextcloud-box-on-ubuntu-core/

Comment: Years later, in 2022, I stumbled across this answer you supplied.  I haven't seen anything else on the web that correctly answers/addresses this issues as it relates to Ubuntu Core.  Thank you for taking the time to provide such clear/concise and most importantly, accurate, information!